# Timer and syslog combination will lead my code to hang situation

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals, syslog

I try to debug issue which is due to the use of timer and syslog function in my program. Here i attach sample program code and logs of terminal and syslog to debug it appropriately.

I don't understand why this program get hangs after a while.
So here i have 2 issues,
1. Sleep is getting break when timer expires as it generates SIGPROF
2. syslog is get hanged after a while or some time in first trial

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#define get_curr_date_time(date_time) \
{ \
   time_t t; \
   time(&t); \
   char *strtime = ctime(&t); \
   strncpy(date_time, strtime, strlen(strtime) - 1); \
}

#define DEBUG_INFO(p,x,arg...) \
{\
   printf("%s:%d,1\n", __func__, __LINE__);\
   char current_time[32] = {0}; \
   printf("%s:%d,2\n", __func__, __LINE__);\
   get_curr_date_time(current_time); \
   printf("%s:%d,3\n", __func__, __LINE__);\
   syslog(LOG_INFO,"[%s] : " p " : "#x"\n", current_time, ##arg);\
   printf("%s:%d,4\n", __func__, __LINE__);\
}

char exit_flag = 0;

typedef struct _test_ctx_
{
   char     timer_init;
   timer_t  timerid;

}test_ctx;

void Timer_Handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
   printf("Timer handler is start\n");
   DEBUG_INFO("timer_hang", "Timer handler is running\n");
   printf("Timer handler is stop\n");
}

int InitTimer(test_ctx *tst_ctx)
{
   int                  status   = 0;
   struct sigaction     sa;
   struct sigevent      sig;

   memset(&sig, 0x00, sizeof(struct sigevent));
   memset(&sa, 0x00, sizeof(struct sigaction));

   do
   {
      sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
      sa.sa_sigaction = Timer_Handler;
      sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
      if (0 != (status = sigaction(SIGPROF, &sa, NULL)))
      {
         printf("Fail to register SIGPROF signal for timer, ret: %d\n", status);
         break;
      }

      sig.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
      sig.sigev_signo = SIGPROF;
      sig.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &tst_ctx->timerid;
      if (0 != (status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sig, &(tst_ctx->timerid))))
      {
         printf("Failed to create timer, ret: %d\n", status);
         break;
      }

      //Timer inited sucessfully
      tst_ctx->timer_init = 1;

   }while(0);

   return status;
}

void DeInitTimer(test_ctx *tst_ctx)
{
   int   status   = 0;

   if (0 != tst_ctx->timer_init)
   {
      //Delete timer
      if (0 != (status = timer_delete(tst_ctx->timerid)))
      {
         printf("Fail to delete timer, ret: %d\n", status);
      }
      tst_ctx->timer_init = 0;
   }
}

int SetTimer(test_ctx *tst_ctx)
{
   int   status   = 0;
   struct itimerspec in;
   memset(&in, 0x00, sizeof(struct itimerspec));

   do
   {
      in.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
      in.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;
      in.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
      in.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

      if (0 != (status = timer_settime(tst_ctx->timerid, 0, &in, NULL)))
      {
         printf("Fail to set timer, ret: %d\n", status);
         break;
      }

   }while(0);

   return status;
}

void terminate_app(int sig)
{
   exit_flag = 1;
   printf("signal %d received exiting application\n", sig);
   DEBUG_INFO("timer_hang", "signal %d received exiting application\n", sig);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int            status   = 0;
   test_ctx       tst_ctx;
   memset(&tst_ctx, 0x00, sizeof(tst_ctx));

   do
   {
      //Register signal handler
      signal(SIGTERM, terminate_app);
      signal(SIGINT,  terminate_app);

      //Init timer
      status = InitTimer(&tst_ctx);
      if (0 != status)
      {
         break;
      }

      while(0 == exit_flag)
      {
         printf("Setting timer\n");
         DEBUG_INFO("timer_hang", "Setting timer");

         //Set Timer
         SetTimer(&tst_ctx);

         printf("Hello!!!\n");
         DEBUG_INFO("timer_hang", "Hello!!!");
         printf("Say!!!\n");

         sleep(5);
      }

   }while(0);

   //De init timer
   DeInitTimer(&tst_ctx);

   return status;
}
```

**Teminal Logs:**

```
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang# ./hang_issue
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!



Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,3
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
main:154,4
Say!!!




Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
main:154,4
Say!!!
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3
Timer_Handler:39,4
Timer handler is stop
Setting timer
main:148,1
main:148,2
main:148,3
main:148,4
Hello!!!
main:154,1
main:154,2
main:154,3
Timer handler is start
Timer_Handler:39,1
Timer_Handler:39,2
Timer_Handler:39,3



^Csignal 2 received exiting application
terminate_app:123,1
terminate_app:123,2
terminate_app:123,3

^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./hang_issue
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang#
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang# killall -s 9 hang_issue
[1]+  Killed                  ./hang_issue
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang#
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang#
```

**Syslog messages:**

```
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang# tail -f /var/log/messages
...

Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:15 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:15 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"



Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:20 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:20 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"



Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Hello!!!"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Timer handler is running\n"
Jan 21 10:52:25 AHMCPU0085 hang_issue: [Wed Jan 21 10:52:25 2015] : timer_hang : "Setting timer"


^C
root@AHMCPU0085:/home/ravi/work/test_app/timer_hang#
```

You will run this test app at your linux machine by doing below steps:

```
# gcc -o hang_issue timer_hang.c -Wall -lrt
# ./hang_issue
... <You will get logs> ...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: `printf()` is not async signal save. So do not call it from signal handlers ... and timer handlers?

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it. Even if i remove all printf from signal handler and timer handler it is getting blocked. So can you suggest me how to resolve hang issue or can you give me some point to debug it more.

Comment: It hangs because `exit_flag` is not `volatile`, allowing the compiler to make assumptions about its value without actually checking it. Also, [`sleep()`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) interacts badly with signals. You should use [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) instead; it will be interrupted by signal delivery, but it'll then return -1 with `errno == EINTR` and `*rem` updated to indicate the un-slept time.

Comment: exit_flag is not volatile: When flag is defined in the same file then compiler is that much intelligent to detect flag is changeable. So hang issue is not due to exit_flag. Thanks for giving idea of nanosleep instead of sleep, i will definitely look for this option.

Comment: (I'm not so sure about `exit_flag` as you are, as it depends on compiler, compiler version, and compiler options used. I'll accept your word, however.) `syslog()` is not async-signal safe either, and it's pretty complex function; it would be no surprise if it blocked (for a long time) in a signal handler. Look, this is very simple: If you use non-[async-signal safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in a signal handler, and your program craps out, **it is your own fault**. Just fix your code, and the hang/blocking will go away.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But i want to operate syslog and timer handler together, So can you provide me some other direction to resolve it. Or i can't use it any other way?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In general, you are better off using a separate thread to handle timeouts, and/or to log to syslog rather than trying to do it in a signal handler. If you absolutely have to log from a signal handler, use a pipe or a socketpair and use low-level I/O, `write()` or `send()`, to write/send from the signal handler. (To get that to syslog, you need another thread or process reading from the pipe and syslogging the messages.)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot use `syslog()` in a signal handler. It is not [async-signal safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), and as a complicated function (opening and closing the connection to syslog as needed), it is no wonder if using it causes your program to fail in odd and varying ways.

Instead, use [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and standard output and standard error streams. For example,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void wr(int fd, const void *const ptr, const size_t len)
{
    const char       *p = (const char *)ptr;
    const char *const q = (const char *)ptr + len;
    ssize_t           n;

    while (p < q) {
        n = write(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > (ssize_t)0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1 || errno != EINTR)
            return;
    }
}

static void wrerr(const char *const string)
{
    if (string != NULL)
        wr(STDERR_FILENO, string, strlen(string));
}

static void wrout(const char *const string)
{
    if (string != NULL)
        wr(STDOUT_FILENO, string, strlen(string));
}
```

Above, `wrout()` and `wrerr()` take only a single string (like `puts()`, except these do not append a newline automatically), and are not as useful as `printf()`, but they are async-signal safe, and safe to use from a signal handler.

Remember that when using Bash, you can use `>out` to redirect standard output to file `out`, and `2>err` to redirect standard error to file `err`. Outputting to a terminal is surprisingly slow, so for any timing, do redirect to files (or better yet, don't output extra debugging information at all).

If you do need to send some output from a signal handler to syslog, you need to use a pipe or a socket pair, and have a thread or a child process read from the other end of that, sending the data to syslog. Then you can just write to the pipe or socket pair (using `write()`) from the signal handler, using only async-signal safe functions. (Obviously, the thread or child process that reads and syslogs the data, does not need to use async-signal safe functions -- after all, it is not a signal handler.)

---

Let's discuss the topic of timeouts in general.

I recommend against using a normal signal for timeouts. If you need signals, say for interrupting a blocking syscall in a specific thread, use a realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0`) instead.

In practice, using a separate thread to handle a set of timeouts works out much better. Here is an example, using less than 400 lines of code, which allows you to use any number of concurrent timeouts, and provides both a volatile flag and a semaphore per timeout for easy use. It uses the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock, which is not susceptible to jumps (UTC seconds, daylight savings time, etc.), but otherwise tries to keep the tick rate of the realtime clock (wall clock):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Number of timeouts to test. */
#ifndef TIMEOUT_TESTS
#define TIMEOUT_TESTS 100000
#endif

/* Seconds per timeout. */
#ifndef TIMEOUT_SECONDS
#define TIMEOUT_SECONDS 0.000000001
#endif

/* Timeout thread worker stack size; uses very few local variables. */
#define TIMEOUT_STACK_SIZE    65536

typedef struct timeout  timeout;
struct timeout {
    struct timeout      *next;
    struct timespec      abstime;   /* Using CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock */
    sem_t                elapsed;   /* sem_post()ed when elapsed */
    volatile int         pending;   /* Cleared to zero when expires */
};

static volatile int      timeouts_error = -1;
static pthread_t         timeouts_thread;
static pthread_mutex_t   timeout_lock;
static pthread_cond_t    timeout_cond; /* Uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock */
static timeout *volatile timeout_pending = NULL;

static void *timeouts_worker(void *unused __attribute__((unused)))
{
    struct timespec now;
    timeout *curr;
    int err;

    err = pthread_mutex_lock(&timeout_lock);
    if (err) {
        timeouts_error = err;
        pthread_cond_signal(&timeout_cond);
        return (void *)(long)err;
    }

    timeouts_error = 0;
    pthread_cond_signal(&timeout_cond);

    while (!timeouts_error) {

        /* If there are no pending timeouts,
         * all we need to do is wait for a condition. */
        if (timeout_pending == NULL) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&timeout_cond, &timeout_lock);
            continue;
        }

        /* CLOCK_MONOTONIC is used for the timeouts. */
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == -1) {
            timeouts_error = errno;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&timeout_lock);
            return (void *)(long)timeouts_error;
        }

        /* Trigger and remove all timeouts that have elapsed thus far. */
        curr = timeout_pending;
        while (curr != NULL &&
               (curr->abstime.tv_sec < now.tv_sec ||
                (curr->abstime.tv_sec == now.tv_sec &&
                 curr->abstime.tv_nsec <= now.tv_nsec))) {
            timeout *const prev = curr;
            curr = prev->next;
            prev->next = NULL;

            /* Mark 'prev' timeout elapsed. */
            prev->pending = 0;
            sem_post(&(prev->elapsed));
        }

        /* No more timeouts? */
        if (timeout_pending == NULL)
            continue;

        /* Wait for the next one to elapse.
         * TODO: Adjust 'now' according to previous over/undershoots,
         *       Say, by one tenth of previous wakeup error
         *       (i.e. dynamically estimating the _timedwait latency).
         *       This would result in much more accurate timeouts.
        */
        now = timeout_pending->abstime;
        pthread_cond_timedwait(&timeout_cond, &timeout_lock, &now);
    }

    return (void *)0L;
}

static int timeout_free(timeout *const old_timeout)
{
    int err;

    if (old_timeout == NULL)
        return 0;

    err = pthread_mutex_lock(&timeout_lock);
    if (err)
        return errno = err; /* We also leak memory here. */

    /* Remove from timeout_pending chain. */
    if (timeout_pending == old_timeout)
        timeout_pending = old_timeout->next;
    else {
        timeout *temp = timeout_pending;
        if (temp != NULL)
            while (temp->next != NULL)
                if (temp->next == old_timeout) {
                    temp->next = old_timeout->next;
                    break;
                } else
                    temp = temp->next;
    }

    /* Unlock mutex; we no longer need to access the chain. */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timeout_lock);

    /* Poison and free the timeout structure. */
    sem_destroy(&(old_timeout->elapsed));
    old_timeout->next = NULL;
    old_timeout->abstime.tv_sec = 0;
    old_timeout->abstime.tv_nsec = 0;
    old_timeout->pending = 0;

    free(old_timeout);

    return 0;
}


static timeout *timeout_after(const double seconds)
{
    const long sec = (long)seconds;
    const long nsec = (long)(1000000000.0 * (seconds - (double)sec));
    struct timespec now;
    timeout *new_timeout;
    int err;

    /* Negative time is not allowed. */
    if (seconds < 0.0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Get current monotonic time. */ 
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now))
        return NULL;

    new_timeout = malloc(sizeof *new_timeout);
    if (new_timeout == NULL) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sem_init(&(new_timeout->elapsed), 0, 0) == -1) {
        err = errno;
        free(new_timeout);
        errno = err;
        return NULL;
    }

    new_timeout->next = NULL;
    new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + sec + (now.tv_nsec + nsec) / 1000000000L;
    new_timeout->abstime.tv_nsec = (now.tv_nsec + nsec) % 1000000000L;
    new_timeout->pending = 1;

    /* Already elapsed? */
    if (new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec < now.tv_sec ||
        (new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec == now.tv_sec &&
         new_timeout->abstime.tv_nsec <= now.tv_nsec)) {
        new_timeout->next = NULL;
        new_timeout->pending = 0;
        sem_post(&(new_timeout->elapsed));
        return new_timeout;
    }

    /* Get timeout lock, to add to chain. */
    err = pthread_mutex_lock(&timeout_lock);
    if (err) {
        sem_destroy(&(new_timeout->elapsed));
        free(new_timeout);
        errno = err;
        return NULL;
    }


    if (timeout_pending == NULL)
        timeout_pending = new_timeout;
    else
    if (timeout_pending->abstime.tv_sec > new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec ||
        (timeout_pending->abstime.tv_sec == new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec &&
         timeout_pending->abstime.tv_nsec >= new_timeout->abstime.tv_nsec)) {
        new_timeout->next = timeout_pending;
        timeout_pending = new_timeout;
    } else {
        timeout *temp = timeout_pending;

        while (temp->next != NULL &&
               (temp->next->abstime.tv_sec > new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec ||
                (temp->next->abstime.tv_sec == new_timeout->abstime.tv_sec &&
                 temp->next->abstime.tv_nsec >= new_timeout->abstime.tv_nsec)))
            temp = temp->next;

        new_timeout->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = new_timeout;
    }

    /* Timeout chain manipulated; notify and unlock. */
    pthread_cond_signal(&timeout_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timeout_lock);

    errno = 0;
    return new_timeout;
}

static int timeouts_end(void)
{
    if (timeouts_error == 0) {
        int err;
        void *errptr;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&timeout_lock);
        timeouts_error = -1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&timeout_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&timeout_lock);

        err = pthread_join(timeouts_thread, &errptr);
        if (err == 0)
            err = (long)errptr;

        return errno = err;

    } else
    if (timeouts_error != -1) {
        int err;
        void *errptr;

        err = pthread_join(timeouts_thread, &errptr);
        if (err == 0)
            err = (long)errptr;
        else
            err = timeouts_error;

        return errno = err;

    } else
        return errno = ENOENT;
}

static int timeouts_init(void)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t lock_attrs;
    pthread_condattr_t cond_attrs;
    pthread_attr_t attrs;
    void *errptr;
    int err;

    if (timeouts_error != -1)
        return errno = EEXIST;

    /* Initialize timeout_lock as an adaptive mutex. */
    err = pthread_mutexattr_init(&lock_attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_mutexattr_settype(&lock_attrs, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_mutex_init(&timeout_lock, &lock_attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&lock_attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    /* Initialize timeout_cond as a process-private monotonic clock condition variable. */
    err = pthread_condattr_init(&cond_attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cond_attrs, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_condattr_setclock(&cond_attrs, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_cond_init(&timeout_cond, &cond_attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_condattr_destroy(&cond_attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    /* Initialize the thread attributes to a 64k stack. */
    err = pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    err = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, TIMEOUT_STACK_SIZE);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    /* Grab the timeout lock; we'll wait on the cond later. */
    err = pthread_mutex_lock(&timeout_lock);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    /* Start the timeout worker thread. */
    err = pthread_create(&timeouts_thread, &attrs, timeouts_worker, NULL);
    if (err)
        return errno = err;

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    /* Wait for the worker to be ready. */
    pthread_cond_wait(&timeout_cond, &timeout_lock);

    /* Failed? */
    if (timeouts_error != 0) {
        timeouts_error = -1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&timeout_lock);
        err = pthread_join(timeouts_thread, &errptr);
        if (err == 0)
            err = (long)errptr;
        return errno = err;
    }

    /* Unlock. */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timeout_lock);

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    long i;
    timeout *t;

    if (timeouts_init()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize timeouts: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Testing:\n");
    fflush(stderr);

    for (i = 1L; i <= TIMEOUT_TESTS; i++) {

        t = timeout_after(0.000000001);
        if (t == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Test %ld of %ld failed: Cannot obtain a timeout: %s.\n", i, (long)TIMEOUT_TESTS, strerror(errno));
            timeouts_end();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("Timeout %ld of %ld: ", i, (long)TIMEOUT_TESTS);
        fflush(stdout);

        /* Wait for timeout to elapse. */
        sem_wait(&(t->elapsed));

        printf("Elapsed.\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        timeout_free(t);
    }

    if (timeouts_end()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in disarming timeouts: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "No errors.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Since we have a dedicated timeout worker thread, the above uses `pthread_cond_timedwait()` to wait for the next timeout to occur (with the condition variable set to use the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock source), or a signal (by another thread that a new timeout was inserted).

To interrupt blocking syscalls, add a `pthread_t thread` to the `timeout` structure, have the `timeout_after()` set it to `pthread_self()`. Install a realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+0` for example) handler (with an empty body -- it's the delivery that counts, not what the handler does). Finally, add `pthread_kill(curr->thread, SIGRTMIN+0)` to `timeouts_worker()` to raise the signal in the target thread.

The above implementation uses a simple sorted linked list, `timeout_pending`, to keep the currently pending timeouts. This yields *O(N)* behaviour in adding, removing, and triggering the timeouts, which is quite suboptimal if you have hundreds or thousands of concurrent timeouts. Replace the list handling with a binary min-heap for much better performance with lots of concurrent timeouts.

Also, it is not necessary to *always* signal the timeout worker that a new timeout was added. Since the adder holds the mutex, it would be sufficient to only signal when the new timeout was added as the next to elapse.

The code compiles, but I've not checked the logic thoroughly, so there might be some bugs lurking about. If you find any, let me know, and I shall try to fix them. (I'm quite certain the algorithm and approach itself works, though.)

I do not consider the above code copyrightable, as it is so straightforward, but in case someone does, I consider it to be in Public Domain, and in those jurisdictions that do not have the legal concept, licensed under Creative Commons Zero license. In short: Do what you wish with it, but there are no guarantees, and you cannot blame me for any breakage.

Questions? Comments? Bug fixes?